# Jquery radio button doesnt register click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have the following two `div` block:

```
<div class="span9" id="lejer">
   <div class="span9" id="udejer">
```

Note that in my Html they have alot of things within them but for the sake of keeping it short i will not post all of it.

At the top of my document i have the following radio buttons:

```
    <div class="controls">
<label class="radio inline">
    <input id="optionsRadios1" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="option1" checked="" id="select_lejer">
    Jeg er lejer
</label>
    <label class="radio inline">
        <input id="optionsRadios1" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="option1" checked="" id="select_udlejer">
      <p style="padding-left:1em">  Jeg er udlejer</p>
    </label>

</div>
```

Now to toggle between the visibilty of the two div tags i have created the following jquery:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('#select_lejer').click(function(){
        $('#udlejer').hide();
        $('#lejer').toggle( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
        });
    });

    $('#select_udlejer').click(function(){
        $('#lejer').hide();
        $('#udlejer').toggle( "slow", function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });

});
```

When the page is loaded one of the `radio buttons` are checked and one of the divs are correctly hidden `HOWEVER` when i click the radio buttons nothing happens.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Contextually, *click* events are generally for buttons and links - use [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) on inputs

Comment: Your rapidly button had two ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID must be unique in HTML, you are using `optionsRadios1` for radiobuttons

Your code

```
<input id="optionsRadios1" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="option1" checked="" id="select_lejer">
<input id="optionsRadios1" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="option1" checked="" id="select_udlejer">
```

Remove `id="optionsRadios1"` from above code.

Also you are provide `ID` twice to radio elements

- `id="optionsRadios1"` and `id="select_lejer"`
- `id="optionsRadios1"` and `id="select_udlejer"`

Additionaly, use `change` event instead of `click`